# Prove $x_n=n^2-n$ sequence converges to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Prove $x_n=n^2-n$ sequence converges to $\infty$

Here is my proof, I proved this using two attempt. Is there anything wrong please tell me?

**$1^{st}$ attempt,**

Let $ M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M>0$,

$$x_n>M\Longleftrightarrow n^2-n>M\Longleftrightarrow n>\sqrt{M+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2} $$

By the Archimedian property  $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$N>\sqrt{M+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Then $x_n>M$ whenever $n>N$

therefore $x_n=n^2-n$ sequence converges to $\infty$

**$2^{nd}$ attempt,**

Let $ M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M>0$,

For lower bonded, $x_n=n^2-n\geqslant n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}$ when $n\geqslant2 ,$

take $N > max\{2, \sqrt{2M}\}$. Then $n>N$ implies $n>2$ and $n>\sqrt{2M}  $ thus for $n>N$ we have $x_n>M$

$x_n>M$ whenever $n>N$

therefore $x_n=n^2-n$ sequence converges to $\infty$

Comment: What you did, is perfectly fine...

Comment: Your proofs are fine! Good work!

Comment: $n^2-n\geq n$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @K.defaoite got it thank you

Answer (score 6):

Your two proofs are perfectly correct. With experience, you will be able to omit some details. For exemple, writing
$$ n^2 - n \geq \frac{n^2}{2} \quad \text{ for } n \geq 2$$
hence
$$n^2 - n \longrightarrow \infty$$
will be enough. But to begin, writing all the details is a good way to progress.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer. See why [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20098/446262).

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my answer, I hope it is better now.

Comment: Thank you I upvoted it