# Prove that $x_n = n - 3n^2$ converges to $-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that $x_n = n - 3n^2$ converges to $-\infty$.

Here is my attempt drawing from inspiration from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930097/prove-x-n-n2-n-sequence-converges-to-infty):

*Proof:* Let $M\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M > 0$. Notice that
$$x_n = n - 3n^2 \leq n - n^2 \leq n^2 \text{ for } n\geq 2.$$
Then Choose $N > \max\{2, \sqrt{M}\}$. Then we have $x_n < M$ for $n > N$.

Is this a fine proof?

Comment: If you're trying to show that $x_n$ goes to $-\infty$, why are you comparing it to a positive $M$?

Comment: @Sandejo, I honestly just did similar to the post I linked because my book didn't specify that $M$ has to be negative or positive. But I get your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. You cannot assume that $M>0$. Asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-3n^2=-\infty$ means that, for any $M\in\Bbb R$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies n-3n^2<M.\tag1$$

Here's a way of doing it. If $n\in\Bbb N$, then $n-3n^2\leqslant-n^2$. Now, take $M\in\Bbb R$. If $M\geqslant0$, you *always* have $-n^2\leqslant M$, and therefore $n-3n^2\leqslant M$. And if $M<0$, then $-n^2\leqslant M\iff n\geqslant\sqrt{-M}$. So, take $N\in\Bbb N$  such that $N\geqslant\sqrt{-M}$, and then $(1)$ holds.

Comment: I see. I hope we don't always have to do the $M\geq 0$ or $M < 0$ cases in all these proofs :( .

Comment: May I ask though: In the post that I linked, why was the OP able to assume $M> 0$ in that proof?

Comment: That post was about a limit being $\infty$, and asserting that, for every $M\in\Bbb R$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n>M$ is equivalent to asserting that, for every $M>0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n>M$. It is similar here: asserting that, for every $M\in\Bbb R$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n<M$ is equivalent to asserting that, for every $M<0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n<M$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x_n\le n^2$ won't help you in proving $x_n\to-\infty$. For instance the constant sequence $-1$ verifies this property, but it does not diverge.

Instead you can regroup like this: $\quad x_n=\underbrace{(n-2n^2)}_{\le 0}-n^2\le -n^2$

And now you have the correct sign.

Comment: thank you for that!